# Divi Theme text module

Tags: css, html-lists, divi-theme

**Solved**
(I did not see that Divi added two classes for adding padding two times to `<ul>`'s in both their footer and Text Module. I created a new class to remove the `padding-bottom` to the sub-list item.)

I have created an unordered list in a Divi text module. I added the html for a sub-list item. Divi is adding module bottom padding to the bottom of the module but is also adding it after the sub-list item. I have the html like this:

```
       <li>Item one!</li>
       <li>Item two!
          <ul>
              <li>Sub-list item two.a!</li>
          </ul></li>
```

This is where Divi is adding bottom padding.

```
<li>Item three!</li>
  </ul>
```

I need the bottom padding in this module. Is there a way to keep the padding but prevent it from being added after the sub-list item? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way of going it would be to remove padding for unordered-list within li tag

```css
ul {
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}

li > ul {
   padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I found that Divi adds 2 instances of padding-bottom through its massive CSS file and saw that I needed to add a class to the individual sub-list item I did not want Divi to add padding to the interior <ul> tag. I solved it and didn't see the problem right away, I appreciate your reply.